# Is there a possible way to extract coordinates within a polygon in Google Earth?

Tags: path, kml, google-earth

is there a way to extract coordinates inside a polygon in Google Earth. For example I have a project in which I need to use the coordinates for every 1km^2 in an area and use them in MATLAB. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could use Google Earth to overlay polygons and a grid of coordinates and visually determine your answer, Google Earth does not provide a way to select and export features (grid points) within another feature (a polygon).

However, you could approach the problem by:
 1. saving the polygon feature to a KML file;
 2. parse the KML file using an XML reader in your favorite language;
 3. construct a grid of coordinates that you want to test;
 4. use a library (such as JTS in Java, GEOS in C, Shapely in Python) that implements a [point-in-polygon algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon). MATLAB appears to provide a [point in polygon function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/inpolygon.html).